# Create pages without using routes.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have been using Laravel since version 3 and have also routed each URL I created to routes.php. However, I have seen some projects that don't use routes.php at all but still have URLs (of course). An example is Octobercms. So, my question is how is that even possible? I see zero indication of routing the way Laravel states in their doucmentation

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Are you saying "route without a routs.php file at all" or just that they are setting up their routs.php file differently than you'd normally see?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I am just talking about I have seen some projects that do not have a traditional way of adding URL's to routes.php. I would love to not do that as I feel like it's an un-needed step. By the looks of these projects they seem to agree

Answer (score 1):

When you look at a conventional `routes.php` you see a lot of `Route::get()` `Route::resource()` etc...
Those calls register the routes through the `Route` Facade. Now the thing is, you can register your routes everywhere you want (`Route` has to be accessible and it has to be "early" enough)

For example, if you're developing a package that only has one or two routes, you might want to do that in the `boot` function of your service provider.

But what Laravel does with the `routes.php`, it simply includes it with `require`

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php**

```
$routes = $app['path'].'/routes.php';

if (file_exists($routes)) require $routes;
```

Comment: Yeah, I am just trying to see if I can avoid Route::get() Route::post..that sort of thing. I have been doing that for every single page. Building an ecommerce site. That can get pretty crazy when almost every page has a POST and a GET

Comment: I see... you will need to at least define one route that catches all requests this could be done by `Route::any('{slug}', function($slug){ // handle slug });` and then with slug you would do a db lookup, search a controller class, wathever...
A little sidenote: with the upcoming Laravel 5 release, routes will be defined [in your controller](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-route-annotations)

Comment: oh really!? Sweet! I am glad you told me that. I am about to start a large project that will take time. Should I just move to L5? I remember coming from L3 to L4 and it was a pain.

Comment: Well I personally haven't had any experience with L5 but it seems to be quite nice ;) If you're starting with a new project that will take some time I'd go with version 5. I think the final release is pretty close :)

Comment: Thank you for the information! Yeah, I think I will go ahead to L5. I jumped to L4 when it was still beta and never looked back. howevever, I never stray to far away from the main documentation. That's why my routes.php question came from. But hopefully I can work with the new file structure and hopefully installing packages is still the same! Thanks again mate!

Comment: According to this. Routes.php is the preferred method of dealing with request. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/0ee0c434a3760ae03ff84545c8a298c00dccb15d

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info... Still, you could use one dynamic route to resolve the controller by yourself. Am I guessing right that you want to match an url like this `/user/edit` to match the `editAction` in your `UserController`? (or something similar..)